# Invoke BPEL Web Service in eclipse apache ODE

Tags: web-services, bpel, apache-ode

First of all, i am very much new to BPEL. 
I have a webservice hosted in Tomcat 7.0 and a BPEL deployed in Apache ODE. I have done all this using Eclipse JUNO. Now, when i unable to invoke the web service from eclipse as Apache ODE cannot start while an instance of Tomcat is running. Also i cannot host the web service in Apache ODE and BPEL process in Tomcat. How do invoke the Web service now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then both Tomcat instances run on the same port, which obviously does not work. There are two options:

- use different tomcat configurations with different ports
- use a shared tomcat instance and deploy ODE along with your web service. Eclipse can still manage this Tomcat instance.